# UNable to install LibreOffice in docker Alpine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, alpine-linux, docker-build

Previously i was using simple docker images and installing LibreOffice was not an issue but recently I have decided to move to Alpine Image cause my container size was very large. But in Alpine image i am unable to install libre office. Following is my docker file.

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.4
RUN echo "ipv6" >> /etc/modules && apk update && apk add curl bash && apk add --no-cache icu-libs icu-dev libreoffice \
    && apk remove libreoffice-gnome \
    && apk update \
    && apk add install ghostscript
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 8000
# Entry point and CMD
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/paksign/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Upon building my docker file i am getting following error.

```
> WARNING: This apk-tools is OLD! Some packages might not function
> properly. ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:   so:libicui18n.so.60
> (missing):
>     required by:
>                  libreoffice-common-6.0.6.2-r0[so:libicui18n.so.60]
>                  libreoffice-common-6.0.6.2-r0[so:libicui18n.so.60]
>                  libreoffice-common-6.0.6.2-r0[so:libicui18n.so.60]
>                  libreoffice-common-6.0.6.2-r0[so:libicui18n.so.60]
>                  libreoffice-common-6.0.6.2-r0[so:libicui18n.so.60]
>                  libreoffice-common-6.0.6.2-r0[so:libicui18n.so.60]
>                  libreoffice-common-6.0.6.2-r0[so:libicui18n.so.60]
>                  libreoffice-common-6.0.6.2-r0[so:libicui18n.so.60]
>                  libreoffice-common-6.0.6.2-r0[so:libicui18n.so.60]
```

I have tried googling this problem but apparently there is no feasible solution so I took help from stackoverflow. Anyone having any idea what's wrong please correct me or suggest some solution. Thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE**
Following is my entrypoint.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# ToDo Need to enable this
#until psql $DATABASE_URL -c '\l'; do
#  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
#  sleep 1
#done
#
#>&2 echo "Postgres is up - continuing"
cd app
if [ "x$DJANGO_MANAGEPY_MIGRATE" = 'xon' ]; then
    echo "Django starting to migrate un-applied migrations"
    python manage.py migrate --noinput
fi

if [ "x$DJANGO_MANAGEPY_COLLECTSTATIC" = 'xon' ]; then
    echo "Django starting to collect static data"
    python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
fi

if [ "x$DJANGO_LOADDATA" = 'xon' ]; then
    # python manage.py addmedia --source /home/paksign/app/app/document/fixtures/files/c2hvYWliQHd1a2xhLmNvbQ --mediadir c2hvYWliQHd1a2xhLmNvbQ/
    # python manage.py loaddata document/fixtures/initial/documentmeta.json
    # python manage.py loaddata document/fixtures/initial/basepermission.json
    # python manage.py loaddata document/fixtures/initial/signingposition.json
    # python manage.py loaddata document/fixtures/initial/signingpermission.json
    # python manage.py loaddata document/fixtures/initial/baseactivity.json
    # python manage.py loaddata document/fixtures/initial/signingactivity.json
    python manage.py loaddata taxing/fixtures/province-taxing-table-initial-data.json
fi

exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below  line form dockerfile and also share a entrypoint.sh script.

FROM alpine:latest

Comment: by using alpine latest version i am getting following `error ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  so:libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.67.0 (missing):`

Comment: Due to above change my image is build.

Comment: which change @raka?

Comment: FROM alpine:latest
RUN echo "ipv6" >> /etc/modules && apk update && apk add curl bash && apk add --no-cache icu-libs icu-dev libreoffice \
    && apk update \
    && apk add install ghostscript
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 8000
# Entry point and CMD
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/paksign/app/entrypoint.sh"]

Comment: but upon usinf alpine latest i am getting following error
 `
 so:libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.67.0 (missing):
    required by:
                 libcmis-0.5.1-r3[so:libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.67.0]
                 libcmis-0.5.1-r3[so:libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.67.0]
                 libcmis-0.5.1-r3[so:libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.67.0]
`

Comment: Removing intermediate container 5a78f35df21e
 ---> 26f6ec8e67a4
Step 3/4 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in cb7fbf258a59
Removing intermediate container cb7fbf258a59
 ---> 530162efac7f
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["/home/paksign/app/entrypoint.sh"]
 ---> Running in 113ea369b075
Removing intermediate container 113ea369b075
 ---> 077c082c583c
Successfully built 077c082c583c
Successfully tagged libofficeme:latest